# How to change the level of AX info messages

Tags: x++, axapta

In Dynamics AX 2009 I am trying to determine the level of indentation of an info message.  What I want is something similar to this:

```
Prefix
    Info1
    Info2
Prefix2
    Info3
```

I found this:

http://www.doens.be/2010/05/the-ax-infolog/

But don't want to use a loop, so I thought something like this might work:

```
setprefix("Prefix");    

{
    info("Info1");
    info("Info2");
}

setprefix("Prefix2");

{
    info("Info3");
}
```

But it doesn't.  Is there a way to do this in x++, and what are the rules as to what indent level is currently active?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`setPrefix` in AX sets *(adds)* the prefix for the current execution scope, and when leaving the scope the prefix is automatically reset to the previous level. You can use `getPrefix` to check the current execution prefix.

2 hacks can help you recieve the expected result:

**#1**

```
static void TestJob(Args _args)
{
    void sub1()
    {
        setprefix("Prefix");
        info("Info1");
        info("Info2");
    }

    void sub2()
    {
        setprefix("Prefix2");
        info("Info3");
    }
    ;

    setPrefix("Main");
    sub1();
    sub2();
}
```

**#2**

```
static void TestJob(Args _args)
{
    setPrefix("Main");
    info("Prefix\tInfo1");
    info("Prefix\tInfo2");
    info("Prefix2\tInfo3");
}
```

Comment: WOW Job #2 needs more attention.  I didn't realize that a tab would actually force the next prefix level in some way.  Great post

Comment: Indeed Job #2 is awesome. I just tried it with multiple tabs and it creates multiple sublevels as needed.