# How to insert label in the info with %n - field's values?

Tags: label, axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012

I have to stamp to video a simple string, with **label** and field's values.

I have this code:

```
 info (strFmt (" @SYS334481: %1 , @SYS4569: %2 " , myTable.AliasUser, myTable.Day) );
```

I have an output looklike this :

> Alias user , Day

I haven't the field's values. I also tried to use this way ,  but I have a syntax error:

```
info (strFmt (" "@SYS334481": %1 , "@SYS4569": %2 " , myTable.AliasUser, myTable.Day ));
```

What is the correct way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While making a specific label will work, I would prefer the simpler:

```
info(strFmt('%1: %2, %3: %4', fieldPname(myTable,AliasUser), myTable.AliasUser, fieldPname(myTable,Day), myTable.Day));
```

I often use this technique with [setPrefix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6664856/how-to-change-the-level-of-ax-info-messages) instead:

```
setPrefix(strFmt('%1: %2, %3: %4', fieldPname(myTable,AliasUser), myTable.AliasUser, fieldPname(myTable,Day), myTable.Day));
info("More specific message here");
```

If only one field use the `PrefixField` macro:

```
setPrefix(#PrefixField(myTable,AliasUser));
info("More specific message here");
```

or the `PrefixFieldValue` sister:

```
setPrefix(#PrefixField(myTable, AliasUser, myTable.AliasUser+':'));
info("More specific message here");
```

Answer (score 3):

I found a possible solution, It's to creat a new **label** with %n inside.

I create a label looklike :

*@xx00000 = "Alias User: %1 - Day: %2"*

I used this syntax:

```
info (strFmt ("@xx00000" , myTable.AliasUser, myTable.Day) );
```

I don't know if It's the better solution but It works so well.

If do you have any other solution, write well, will be more information, thanks this community.

enjoy!